# Adjust brightness of external monitor with only one button

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, external-display, brightness

At work, in addition to the company laptop, we are given an external monitor (AOC 2270W) to work with two screens via a HDMI connection (working on Windows 7).

The problem is the brightness of the external monitor is too high and I don't see how to adjust it. The monitor appears to have only the power button (which does some sort of calibration when pushed sideways, but still leaves the brightness too high) and from Control Panel I only modify the settings of my laptop's screen, even when the monitor is set as principal screen. Moreover, as far as I can see there's no other application to control the settings of the monitor...

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: According to the [manual](http://aoc-europe.com/en/products/e2270swn#support-download) the monitor should have "i-Menu makes it easy to adjust your monitor display setting by using on screen menus instead of the OSD button on the monitor.". I think it is part of the driver package. Did you install the drivers for the monitor?

Comment: I hadn't installed the drivers, now I downloaded them from your link and installed them. Before it was using a 2006 driver from Microsoft (generic?), now it's using a driver from 11/01/2013 of AOC... but the i-menu still doesn't show up

Comment: I've been contacted by the IT department and they ended up giving me a different monitor with several buttons to configure the brightness and othe settings. They first gave me the i-Menu, but it didn't seem to change anything, probably due to some driver incompatibility.

I guess this is it for this question (but thanks anyway @DavidPostill).

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Comment: My comment is kind of a non-answer, in the sense that I couldn't reach anyone who knew a solution, but this doesn't imply that in the future somebody else may come up with some proper solution

Answer (score 2):

You adjust the brightness with just that one button.

1. Single click the button till you select brightness.
2. Wait till it enters the menu.
3. Adjust the brightness with the button.

Answer (score -1):

You adjust the brightness with just that one button.

1. 1.Single click the button till you select brightness.
2. Wait till it enters the menu.
3. Adjust the brightness with the button to your desire.
4. When it's already too bright, you will need to get to 100% and it will just automatically back to 0%